# How to execute a command in a "while" loop after a background command has finished executing, while still looping through the loop

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How can I execute a command in a `while` loop after a background command inside the loop has finished executing, while still looping through the loop? I've included comments in the code to explain what I mean more clearly

```
while read file; 
      # run command 1 in the background. command 1 takes in "file" as an argument and does some processing on it
      # run command 2 after command 1 is done, but keep going through the loop. Command 2 deletes "file"
done
```

EDIT: One solution I can think of is to put the body of the while loop in a script and to run that in the background, but I'm not sure that's the best way of doing it, and if there's a better way

EDIT 2: I tried @steeldriver's suggestion (see comments), but I'm getting a syntax error
Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e 

MONITORDIR="/home/user/random/ready_for_mapping/"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE; do
    file_dir=$(echo $NEWFILE | rev | cut -d / -f2- | rev)
    if [[ $NEWFILE == *"paired"* ]]; then
        while (( $(ls -1 $file_dir | wc -l) != 2 )); do
            sleep 1
        done

        { kallisto quant -i /home/user/random/Caenorhabditis_elegans.WBcel235.cdna.all.index -o $file_dir -t 12 $(ls $file_dir -1 | head -1) $(ls $file_dir -1 | tail -1) ;
        rm $file_dir/*gz }&
    else
        { kallisto quant -i /home/user/random/Caenorhabditis_elegans.WBcel235.cdna.all.index -o $file_dir --single -t 12 -l 250 -s 30 $(ls $file_dir *gz) ;
        rm $file_dir/*gz }&
    fi
done
```

Here's the error I get:

./second_queue: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Comment: Doesn't the `wait` command fit the bill here - like you asked previously [How can I run commands in batches?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1257199/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver where are you suggesting to put the `wait`? Because if I `wait` after command 1, wouldn't that halt the `while` loop?

Comment: It would halt the while loop until the bacgrounded command exits, then execute the following command - which seems to be exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: @steeldriver no I don't want to halt the while loop. I'd like the while loop to keep going no matter what. What I want is to have command 1 run in the background, and command 2 to wait till command 1 to execute, but I don't want the while loop to wait till command 1 finishes

Comment: @steeldriver I added some more details to make my question clearer

Comment: So in that case you would need to place `command 2` in the background as well I think ex. `{ command1 ; command 2; }&`

Comment: @steeldriver yes this is what I'm looking for (some way to group the commands and run them together in the background)

Comment: @steeldriver now I get a syntax error though. I've included all my code above, I seem to be missing something. I've also included the error

Comment: It's missing semicolons between `rm $file_dir/*gz` and the closing `}`

Comment: @steeldriver Oh I forgot to mention this solved the problem (I upvoted your last comment). Post it as an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

Remember the PID of the long running process, and use that for checking in the loop . `bash` returns the PID of the background process in `$!` just after you put the job in the  background.

Do something like (untested):

```
command_1 &
cpid=$!
  
....
  
# inside the loop,
if [[ -d /proc/$cpid ]] ; then
   : command_1 still running
else
   : command_1 not running
fi
```

Comment: problem is the long running process depends on what the while loop reads, so I can't put it outside the while loop

Comment: Then put it inside the `while`. You may have to make `cpid` an array.